# Getting the name of a function after it got called

Tags: r

I have saved a function called "type" in a list "funList" like so

```
funList <- list(type = function() { 
    funname <- ??? 
    print(funname) # should return "type" }
)
```

In other parts of my code I call this function but never by its name but instead by its position in the list, e.g.:

```
funList[[1]]()
```

In reality function "type" is of course way more complicated, but there is a part in its function body that uses the function's own name. How can I retrieve the name when I only call it by position? In other words, how can I have the last function call print "type".

Comment: You didn't create a named function. You did create a named list. Your anonymous function has no way to know about the name you've given it in the named list. You'd have to create a wrapper function that creates both the list and the function at the same time and can create a proper scope to store the value. Of course that would break if you renamed the list at all. What are you *really* trying to do? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Very broadly speaking, this code is going to be part of specific DSL I write to apply functions to specific columns in a data frame. I need to implement it so that first these functions are collected and stored in a container (funList) and then applied consecutively on columns in a data frame. Perhaps the name of the column, i.e. type could also appear as a function argument but I thought it would be nicer to write it like I did. Anyways, I really would appreciate some hints about how I could come up with the wrapper solutions you mentioned.

Comment: The kind of thing you are trying to do is accomplished in R using non-standard evaluation. This is a complex and subtle subject. For a good introduction see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#nse

Comment: This request begs for an answer using an environment.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hacky solution, but the idea here is to extract the number from `match.call()` and find the corresponding function name from `names(funList)`.

```
funList <- list(
  type = function() { 
    # Do something
    getFunName(match.call())
  },
  bob = function() {
    # Do something else
    getFunName(match.call())
  }
) 

getFunName <- function(call) {
    names(funList)[as.numeric(gsub(".*?([0-9]+)(.*)", "\\1", as.character(call)[1]))]
}
```

Output:

```
> funList[[1]]()
[1] "type"
> funList[[2]]()
[1] "bob"
```

Comment: If course this would break with things like `funList[[1]](2)` or `lapply(funList, function(f) f())`

Comment: Thanks -- edited to deal with the first issue, not sure what to do about the second. Would be interested to see what others come up with!